# VS Code and Pycharm test command line

Tags: visual-studio-code, pycharm, command-line-arguments

In PyCharm you can set the command line parameters you want to test in your program in Run|Configurations.  Where is this hidden in VSCODE?  And I assume it does not exist in Wing?

Answer (score 0):

Project| [filename] properties
click on Debug
Enter the command line on the Script Arguments line/